# Facebook Api callback not working

Tags: perl

```
            #!/usr/bin/perl -w

            use WWW::Facebook::API;
            use WWW::Facebook::API::Auth;
            use WWW::Facebook::API::Canvas;
            use HTTP::Request;
            use LWP;

            use CGI;                                    # load CGI routines
            $q = CGI->new;                              # create new CGI object
            print $q->header,                           # create the HTTP header
            $q->start_html('Facebook App'),          # start the HTML
            $q->h1('Facebook Authentication'),          # level 1 header
            $q->end_html;                               # end the HTML

            my $facebook_api      = '-------------';
            my $facebook_secret   = '----------------';
            my $facebook_clientid = '---------------------';

            my $client = WWW::Facebook::API->new(
            desktop         => 0,
            api_version     => '1.0',
            api_key         => $facebook_api,
            secret          => $facebook_secret,   
            callback        => 'http://localhost/perl/facebook.pl',

            );

            $client->app_id($facebook_clientid);
            $q->redirect($client->get_login_url());
```

Afterlogin to facebook the callback url is not working getting the facebook appication is underconstruction. I dont want to specify the call back url in facebook itself. I want to specify the callback in the source code.

Answer (score 5):

> `callback        => 'http://localhost/perl/facebook.pl',`

Facebook can't make the callback request to `http://localhost` - your localhost is not their localhost!

You have to use a public facing URL.

Comment: The local host folder is there. And the redirect code also running from that folder only. how to overcome the callback url. when i am not set the callback url in the facebook itself.

Comment: Only HTTP requests originating from your computer can reach your localhost. The HTTP request that Facebook will send can't reach it (because since Facebook are not you, they are sending the request from one of their computers, not from your computer). You need a public facing URL. `http://localhost/` can never be public facing.

Comment: is there any way to fix this.

Comment: Yes. **Use a public facing URI for your callback**

Comment: can you me how to use Use a public facing URI for callback. is it defining in the facebook canvas url.

Comment: Thanks for all the detailed explanation for my questions.

Comment: You run the web server on a network interface that is either directly connected to the Internet (i.e. not behind NAT) or use port forwarding to get the same effect (and make sure that no firewall blocks attempts to connect to the web server port). Then you use the IP address of that interface (either directly in the URL or with a hostname that public DNS points at that IP)